# How to delete an object from a numpy array without knowing the index

Tags: python, list, numpy

Is it possible to delete an object from a numpy array without knowing the index of the object but instead knowing the object itself?

I have seen that it is possible using the index of the object using the np.delete function, but I'm looking for a way to do it having the object but not its index.

Example:

> [a,b,c,d,e,f]
>
> x = e

I would like to delete `x`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can find the index/indices of the object using [np.argwhere](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html), and then delete the object(s) using [np.delete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).

Example:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
index = np.argwhere(x==3)
y = np.delete(x, index)
print(x, y)
```

Comment: Recently applied this to a pandas dateframe where I needed a list of all the unique strings in a group but then needed to erase the blanks (' ') from that list.This helped me put together an elegant solution ------->    
`b['A'] = b['A'].apply(lambda x: np.delete(x,np.argwhere(x=='')))`

Answer (score 28):

Cast it as a numpy array, and **mask it out**:

```
x = np.array(list("abcdef"))

x = x[x!='e']  # <-- THIS IS THE METHOD

print x
# array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'])
```

Doesn't have to be more complicated than this.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem of deleting the value.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that I'm not actually putting the x[x!='e'] back into the x variable?

Comment: Don't "Please..." me. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: I removed the please. It was sarcastic, but after reading my own comment i realized that it came off as douchy. Anyhow this is the simplest answer.

Comment: Don't worry I'm not butt-hurt

Comment: You can't actually delete a value from an array (as an in-place operation).  You'll always get a new array.

Comment: @hpaulj I see your point but, if you overwrite the variable it was stored in anyway, then what difference does it make. even if there was an inplace operation that did deletion in in numpy arrays, somewhere in your computer the array would still get loaded, used to create a new array and overwritten by that new array.

Comment: Some posters worry about copies - fearing either a time penalty or excessive memory use.

Answer (score 6):

Boolean indexing or masking is a good basic way of selecting, or removing specific elements of an array

You talk about removing a specific 'object'.  Let's take that literally and define an array of dtype object:

```
In [2]: x=np.array(['a','b','c','d','e'],dtype=object)
In [3]: x
Out[3]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype=object)
In [4]: x=='d'   # elements that equal 'd'
Out[4]: array([False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [5]: x!='d'    # elements that don't
Out[5]: array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [6]: x[x!='d']   # select a subset
Out[6]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'], dtype=object)
```

Behind the scenes `argwhere` and `delete` use this.  Note that `argwhere` uses the `x==d` boolean array, converting it to array indices.  And constructing mask like this is one way that `delete` operates.

There are some important limits:

- that equality (or not equality) test has to work for your values.  It might not if the elements are floats.
- deleting from a 1d array is easier than from a 2d (or larger) one.  With 2d you have to decide whether to delete a row, a column, or an element (and in the process flattening the array).
- deleting only one element of that matches is a bit trickier.

For some cases it might be better to `.tolist()` the array and use a list method.

```
In [32]: xl=x.tolist()
In [33]: xl.remove('d')
In [34]: np.array(xl,dtype=object)
Out[34]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'], dtype=object)
```

There's no exact equivalent to `list.remove` for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [np.setdiff1d(a,b)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html), it returns all **unique** elements from a that are not in b.

```
>>> arr = np.array(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
>>> to_remove = ['b', 'c']
>>> np.setdiff1d(arr, to_remove)
array(['a', 'd', 'e', 'f'], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])`

Then

`arr = [x for x in arr if arr != 'e']`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi-dimension np array:

```
arr= np.array([1,2,3,], [1,2,3,4],['a','b'])
```

You should do this way to remove specific values:

#### Create a boolean mask of values to be deleted

```
mask = arr == 3
```

#### Delete elements from the array using the boolean mask

```
new_arr = np.delete(arr, np.where(mask))
```

#### Print the new array

```
print(new_arr)
```

#### But in this way shape is changing. for example, if I have (12,3) ndarray it will be converted to (36,). To keep it fixed like (12,3):

#### Create a boolean mask of values to be deleted

```
mask = arr == 3
```

#### Flatten the boolean mask

```
flat_mask = np.ravel(mask)
```

#### Delete elements from the array using the flattened boolean mask

```
 new_arr = np.delete(arr, np.where(flat_mask))
```

#### Reshape the new array to the original shape

new_arr = new_arr.reshape(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1])

#### Print the new array

```
print(new_arr)
```

I hope it will be useful for you.